# Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}' rxjs6

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, angular6

Please view the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { StudentsInfo } from '../studentInfo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-student',
  templateUrl: './delete-student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-student.component.css']
})

export class DeleteStudentComponent  {

public itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<StudentsInfo>;
public items: Observable<StudentsInfo[]>;

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {

this.itemsCollection = this.db.collection<StudentsInfo>('/Stud_Info');
//this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();

  // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
  // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
  // get the data and the id use the map operator.
  this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as StudentsInfo;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data}
    })
  ));
}

  // Deleting a Student from Firestore
  public deleteStudent(docId:string) {
    this.itemsCollection.doc(docId).delete();
  }
}
```

**Problem**: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) documentation of angularfire2. 
I have done everything according to the documentation needed and the according to the latest rxjs6 release.

The final angular application Runs fine but while doing ng build --prod --aot this error occurs.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15548#issuecomment-387009186

Comment: All the changes needed for rxjs6 have been implemented in the above code. But its still getting ERROR.

Comment: Have you verified the type returned by `this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges()`? like do a `tap(changes => { console.log(typeof changes) })` before your `map` inside the pipe. It seems you're not getting an array but rather an empty object.